# GoQuery Response Code

Tags: http, go, goquery

In GoQuery, if I create a snippet as follows:

```
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

where s is a valid url, I can see the error string, but if the page is returning a 403, how do I find out and stop instead of letting my code run?

Is there a way to find the http response using Goquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `NewDocument` gives you the chance to bail based on a status code, but you can use `NewDocumentFromResponse` instead. E.g.:

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Check for a 200 status (or a non-403, or whatever you want)
if res.StatusCode == 200 {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromResponse(res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // ...
}
```